# How can I retrieve specific values from this Core Data function?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to link together the following data:

```
    for member in self.markersArray {
        var coordinate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Coordinate", into: managedObjectContext)
        coordinate.setValue(member.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        coordinate.setValue(member.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        coordinate.setValue(mapName, forKey: "name")
    }
```

so that later I can refer to this array of latitude and longitude values by mapName. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that a fetch request returns an array containing only the Coordinate objects with a given mapName by specifying a predicate for the fetch request, eg.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@", yourMapName)
```

But storing the same map name multiple times, once for each Coordinate, is inefficient (particularly if you subsequently want to change the map name - you have to update all the relevant Coordinate objects).  An alternative approach would be to add another entity (eg. `Map`) which has one attribute (`mapName`) and a to-many relationship (`coordinates`) to the Coordinate entity.  Your Coordinate entity will then not need a `name` attribute, but will instead have a to-one relationship (`map`) to the `Map` entity (the `coordinates` and `map` relationships being mutual inverses).  To "link together" the Coordinate objects, you would create a `Map` object, set its `mapName` attribute, and then assign it to `map` relationship for each Coordinate object:

```
let newMap = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Map", into: managedObjectContext)
newMap.setValue(mapName, forKey:"mapName")
for member in self.markersArray {
    var coordinate = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Coordinate", into: managedObjectContext)
    coordinate.setValue(member.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    coordinate.setValue(member.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
    coordinate.setValue(newMap, forKey: "map")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Saved the day.

Comment: Actually, I get the following error: * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath name not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Coordinate id=1>'. What did I do wrong? I put in exactly what you said: fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@", farm) -> where farm is name of the map

Comment: If you are fetching Coordinates, just traverse the relationship to access the map name: NSPredicate(format:"map.name == %@","farm").

Comment: Why not when fetching Map? Coordinates doesn't have any more "map.name" than Map.

Comment: Also I got this error: to uncaught exception 'keypath map.name not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Coordinate id=1>'

Comment: I think you meant it for fetching Map. It doesn't throw an error now but lists all the coordinates not just for specified mapname.

Comment: I did mean when fetching Coordinates, but I guessed wrongly the name of the relationship.  I see from your follow-up question that you have called the inverse relationship "newRelationship".  So the key path you need to use in the predicate is "newRelationship.name", ie the predicate is NSPredicate(format:"newRelationship.name == %@", "farm").

Comment: For a Coordinate object, the value of the newRelationship property is a Map object.  So the key path "newRelationship.name" refers to the name attribute of that Map object.

Comment: So you mean a relationship would be a property of an object? I thought it's a relationship, and if I want to add properties, I would just add attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141475/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-konyv12).